# Get selected Value from Lookup Dropdown on ItemAdded

Tags: development, event-receivers, lookup-column, splistitem

I am attempting to grab the text value of a lookup dropdown after an Item is Added.

The way I'm currently doing this, gives me the string 23#ADMIN, which is the combined ID and text. I could go the dirty route and parse this text, but I figure there must be a way to just grab ONLY the text portion without manipulation.

I'm currently doing this like so:

```
SPListItem requestItem = properties.ListItem;               
var tradeClass = requestItem[tradeClassCol].ToString();
```

How can I accomplish grabbing just the selected item's text? And if so, is there a simpler way to just grab the ID as well?

EDIT:

I have also attempted [this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/102038/get-selected-value-of-dropdown-choice-list-item), but have had no luck. I get the error "Column XXX does not exist..." I think this may have something to do with it being a Lookup column?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

`string value = (new SPFieldLookupValue(item["FieldName"] as String)).LookupValue`

Answer (score 0):

I used it like this

```
string value = (new SPFieldLookupValue(properties.ListItem["FieldName"].ToString())).LookupValue;
```